# How can I serialize a list via Django REST Framwork

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views, serialization

I have a function which base on different Pandas processes it result a list (`[6, 6, 6]`). My question is how can I serialize it with `Django REST Framwork`. I tried to implement the documentation bit I just get different errors. Unfortunately I am newby in rest, and this is the fist time when I build `Django` with `API` endpoint.

Here is my attempt:

**[serializers.py]**

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.IntegerField()
```

**[views.py]**

```
class TestListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Test().test_list[0] # This results the list --> [6, 6, 6]
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
```

Comment: What is **`Test()`** here? Is that a model?

Comment: Is that is class which process data and resulted the  [6, 6, 6] list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no `Model`, you don't have to use `queryset` attribute or `ListCreateAPIView` at all. You can use [**`APIView`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/?q=APIView) class as

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class MyTestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_list_data = Test().test_list[0]  # get the data
        serializer = TestSerializer(my_list_data)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

and change your serializer as,

```
 class TestSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = serializers.IntegerField()
```

**Note**: I don't think there is much difference between `ListSerializer` and `ListField`, but I would recommend  `ListSerializer` anyway

Comment: Thank you the answer, it helped me a lot.